# java generic how to ensure type has specified annotation?

Tags: java, android, generics, annotations, android-room

I'm trying to create a generic class in android using Java but I want to make sure that the type would take specific classes with specific annotations like this:
 I have class `Table` with annotation `@Entity`

```
@Entity
public class Table{}
```

and the generic class should only accept objects that have the `@Entity` annotation

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept! And welcome to upvote privileges!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: not possible.

Annotations represent meta information that isn't available when constructing classes using generic type parameters.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check class annotation you have to use Reflection 
http://static.javadoc.io/org.reflections/reflections/0.9.10/org/reflections/Reflections.html
`getTypesAnnotatedWith` is the function you need

```
final Reflections reflections = new Reflections(packagePrefix);
    final Set<Class<?>> namedClasses = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Named.class);
    for (final Class<?> namedClass : namedClasses) {

    }
```

Comment: That is not what he is asking for.